# Spring Oauth does not seem to decode the client secret

Tags: spring, oauth

I'm trying to get to a point where I can dynamically register new clients for my Oauth server. The problem that I have (or the issue that I'm trying to understand) is that initially without using the password encoder the client secrets where stored in the DB as plain text.

After googling around I found that one has to set a PasswordEncoder which will handle the encoding/decoding of the client secret.

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
}
```

Now I do in fact see the encoded client secret being stored in the DB. The issue is that now when requesting a token from the service I'm forced to use the encoded client secret when I request a new token (instead of using the plain text version)

```
curl -k -u 'TEST_USER:05a2fcc7-7759-4354-9366-a7c8cf650aae' http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -X POST -d 'response_type=token&client_id=TEST_USER&username=TEST_USERNAME&password=TEST_PASSWORD&scope=process&grant_type=password'
```

{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}

Where as if I use the encoded client secret, the service generates the token as it should.

The thing that I was trying to achieve was having the password encoded in the DB and being able to use the plain text version i the request.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking, the solution to this is to use a DelegatingPasswordEncoder instead of BCrypt directly as I was using (which would not be obvious from the code sample in the original question).

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```